# how to setup access/error log for http.ListenAndServe

Tags: go

I am using the following for a simple server. I am wondering how to setup an access log for all the requests logging the timestamp, method, request url and the http response code.

```
http.HandleFunc("/foo", funcFoo)
err := http.ListenAndServe("127.0.0.1:2074", nil)
```

Comment: for simple http.ListenAndServe type implementation you can make use of wrapper functions  as like here https://medium.com/@matryer/the-http-handlerfunc-wrapper-technique-in-golang-c60bf76e6124

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Take a look here: http://github.com/gorilla/handlers

```
http.Handle("/foo", funcFoo)
err := http.ListenAndServe("127.0.0.1:2074", handlers.LoggingHandler(os.Stdout, http.DefaultServeMux))
```

This will log any incoming connections across the whole server. `os.Stdout` can be replaced by anything that provides an `io.Writer` (i.e. a file, a HTTP stream, etc). If you want it to be per-route, you can do:

```
http.Handle("/foo", handlers.LoggingHandler(os.Stdout, funcFoo))
```

It will also work with [gorilla/mux](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux) and other routers/frameworks that are `http.Handler` compatible.

Comment: In case you need to format logs you can use the `CustomLoggingHandler` function.

Comment: seems like Gorilla is now archived and unmaintained. any alternatives?